# Find all Product root categories of a store (Magento 1.7)

Tags: product, category, navigation

I have two websites and am looking to create a dynamic Nav Bar that works across both store fronts.

Because I'm trying to make it dynamic I'll most likely load the current store_id then find the collection related to that.

**Is there a way I can list the names of all the Product root categories for a given website?**

**and is there a way to get all the sub categories of the website?**

Here is a picture of the categories I'm talking about as an example:
[image]

Let me know if you have any questions or need clarification!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it! For those curious,

*First I grabbed the current store I'm in and the root category Ids*

**$store = Mage::app()->getStore();

 $categoryId = $store->getRootCategoryId();**

*Then I loaded the Ids for root categories for the store and separated them into an array to sort through*

**$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId); 

    $categoryChildren = $categories->getChildren(); 

    $categoryArray = explode(',', $categoryChildren);**

*Then I looped through them and grabbed their info*

```
foreach($categoryArray as $category){
            $Category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category);
            echo $Category->getName();
            echo "\r\n";
            echo $Category->getUrl();
            echo "\r\n";
        }
```

Comment: are u getting sub categories of sub categories also ??

Comment: yep, do you need any help?